# the functions in the console but in the DOM they are messed

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, oop

I'm building a trivia game for a bootcamp, when i built the functions and call them they all do their work correctly, but when i call them in the correct order in the browser they messed up.

I tried some scope debugging and it starts working better but now i think the scope is fixed and still doesnt work properly

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#restartbtn").hide();//restart button starts hidden and appears when game ends

```
$(".game-play").on("click", function (xyz3) {//when clicked grab question and display it
    grabQuestions();

    $('.gameplay').empty();
    cons = 0;
    grabQuestions();
});

$("#restartbtn").on("click", function (xyz4) {
    $('#restart').empty();
 cons = 0;
    grabQuestions();

});
function stopCountdown() {
    clearInterval(elements.countdown);
}

function startTimer() {
    elements.interval1 = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000)
}
function stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(elements.interval1);
    $('.timer').html('');
}

function startDelay() {
    stopDelay();
    elements.delay = setTimeout(grabQuestions, 4000)
}

function stopDelay() {
    clearTimeout(elements.delay);
}

function updateTimer() {
    elements.timmer--;
    if (elements.timer < 0) {
        stopTimer();
    }
    else {
        $(".timer").html('<span class="timer">remaining time: ' + elements.timer + '</span>');

    }
}
```

I expected it to run in order but it shows gain over and in the back runs the game

Comment: it's not clear from this what exactly the bug is, but i do see a typo here: `elements.timmer--;` (looks like it should be `elements.timer--;`).

Comment: Thanks for that!! here is the repository if you want to take a look https://github.com/jmrada14/trivia-game

Comment: line 203 `console.log(grabQuestions())` creates an infinite loop (recursively calling `grabQuestions` during execution of `grabQuestions`)